# How to subset data for additional geoms while using facets in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I want additional 'geoms' to only apply to a subset of the initial data.  I would like this subset to be from each units created by facets=~.

My trials using subletting of either the data or of the plotted variables leads to subsetting of the whole data set, rather than the subletting of the units created by 'facets=~'  and in two different ways (apparently dependant on the sorting of the data).

This difficulty is appears with any 'geom' while using 'facets'

```
library(ggplot2)

test.data<-data.frame(factor=rep(c("small", "big"), each=9),
                              x=c(c(1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,1), 2*c(1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,1)),
                              y=c(c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1), 2*c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1)))


factor x y
1   small 1 1
2   small 2 1
3   small 3 1
4   small 3 2
5   small 3 3
6   small 2 3
7   small 1 3
8   small 1 2
9   small 1 1
10    big 2 2
11    big 4 2
12    big 6 2
13    big 6 4
14    big 6 6
15    big 4 6
16    big 2 6
17    big 2 4
18    big 2 2


qplot(data=test.data,
      x=x,
      y=y,
      geom="polygon",
      facets=~factor)+
      geom_polygon(data=test.data[c(2,3,4,5,6,2),],
                   aes(x=x,
                       y=y),
                   fill=I("red"))
```

[image]

```
qplot(data=test.data,
      x=x,
      y=y,
      geom="polygon",
      facets=~factor)+
        geom_polygon(aes(x=x[c(2,3,4,5,6,2)],
                         y=y[c(2,3,4,5,6,2)]),
                     fill=I("red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to draw an additional red polygon in each facet which has as its vertexes the second, third, forth, fifth, sixth (and back to second) vertex of the black polygon? Where those are picked out separately for each facet?

Comment: Also, if you don't indent your image inclusion tags, they will be displayed inline. (I would propose the edit myself, but I don't have the reputation to propose a white-space only edit.).

Comment: Thank you for both comments.  Yes, I wish to plot a second polygon of a subset of the initial data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to subset the data in a first step.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

test.data<-data.frame(factor=rep(c("small", "big"), each=9),
                      x=c(c(1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,1), 2*c(1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,1)),
                      y=c(c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1), 2*c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1)))

subset.test<-ddply(.data=test.data,
                   .variables="factor",
                   function(data){
                     data[c(2,3,4,5,6,2),]})

qplot(data=test.data,
      x=x,
      y=y,
      geom="polygon",
      facets=~factor)+
        geom_polygon(data=subset.test,
                     fill=I("red"))
```

[image]